# Get value from an attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in my page that contains many rows, each row has an image which has an `<a href>` this `<a href>` has two attributes class and `data-delete-id`, so I have a multiple `<a href>` that has the same attributes and the same value for class.

each `<a href>` has a different value for the `data-delete-id` attribute.

In my JavaScript I have this code :

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('.deleteButton').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
                // get jquery object access to the button
                var $thisButton = $(this);
                // this gets that data directly from the HTML
                var id = $thisButton.data('delete-id');
                if(confirmed) {
                    alert("<?php echo site_url('users/deleteUser')?>" + '/' + id);
                }

            });

        });

</script>
```

So when I click on some `<a href>` that function well be fired, and it gets the `id` value from the `data-delete-id` attribute.

The problem is that `id` value it's always the value for the first `<a href>` in my HTML code.

I only want to get the value for the `data-delete-id` attribute for the clicked `<a href>`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Post code for `confirmOn()` method. I guess you are passing all matched elements as context

Comment: Well maybe the "confirmOn" binds the events wrong.

Comment: are your rows/hrefs dynamically created? IF so, you have to use ".on".
instead of '.bind' : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Maybe if you use e.target instead of this?

Comment: What is `confirmOn`? If it is part of a library then this should be mentioned as well. Also, without the relevant HTML any suggestions is based on pure speculation. If `.deleteButton` is a class on a button then `this` will never be a link. If you have the button inside the link then you need to navigate back out to the link, i.e: `$(this).closest('a').data('deleteId')` or similar. Again, it is very hard to know without seeing the relevant HTML and the missing information in the regards to `confirmOn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the code for confirmOn [here](https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon/blob/master/jquery.confirmon.js) and it does not seem to register with each item in a set of selected elements. This is a bug with the plugin, but a workaround would be to wrap the whole thing in an `each`.

```
    $(function() {
        $('.deleteButton').each(function() {
            $(this).confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
               // get jquery object access to the button
               var $thisButton = $(this);
               // this gets that data directly from the HTML
               var id = $thisButton.data('delete-id');
               if(confirmed) {
                 alert("<?php echo site_url('users/deleteUser')?>" + '/' + id);
               }
            });
        });
    });
```